# Missing `set_input` in keras

Tags: keras

I notice that in https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html it says that we can set tensorflow op as input of keras model like: `first_layer.set_input(my_input_tensor)`. But I find that keras does not have set_input function:

```
first_layer = Dense(32, activation='relu', input_dim=784)
first_layer.set_input(my_input_tensor)
```

But I get:

```
AttributeError: 'Dense' object has no attribute 'set_input'.
```

What may be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess `set_input()` method is removed in latest versions of Keras. If you see [this documentation](https://keras.io/layers/containers/) of Keras, there is a function called `set_input()` function of `keras.layers.containers.Sequential` class. But its source code is no longer available on Github.

If you look at the source code of [Dense](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/core.py#L699) layer class in Keras, you will see that there is no such method called `set_input()` as well. If you also see the source of [abstract class Layer](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/topology.py#L218) which is the base class for `Dense` layer, you will see there is no such function called `set_input()`.

So, we can conclude, `set_input()` method is probably no longer available in Keras.

Comment: To add to @Wasi, it was removed in Keras 1.1.1, https://github.com/fchollet/keras/commit/92e8a20761bedbde8fd56a02a165884e8132f045